# Prove that $\int_{\Omega}|f_n-f_0|d\mu\rightarrow 0$ (by weaker assumption on Scheffé's lemma: $f_n\xrightarrow{\mu} f_0$)

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I'm dealing with this problem.

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of *nonnegative integrable* functions. Suppose $f_n\xrightarrow{\mu} f_0$ and $\displaystyle\int_\Omega f_nd\mu\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_\Omega f_0d\mu<\infty$. Prove that $\displaystyle\int_{\Omega}|f_n-f_0|d\mu\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} 0$.

If the convergence of $\{f_n\}$s to $f_0$ were *almost everywhere*, then the problem would become *Scheffé's lemma*.

By convergence in measure, for each $\epsilon>0$ and natural $n$, define :
$\displaystyle E^\epsilon_n:=\{\omega\in\Omega\;;\;|f_n-f_0|(\omega)\geq\epsilon\} \;\wedge\;F_n^\epsilon:=\Omega-E^\epsilon_n$
$$\int_\Omega |f_n-f_0|d\mu=I_1+I_2\quad;\quad I_1=\int_{E^\epsilon_n} |f_n-f_0|d\mu\;\wedge\;I_2=\int_{F^\epsilon_n} |f_n-f_0|d\mu$$
We have $\mu(E_n^\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ and $|f_n-f_0|<\epsilon$ over $F_n^\epsilon$.
But I can't control the terms $|f_n-f_0|$ in $I_1$ and $\mu(F_n^\epsilon)$ in $I_2$ when the measure of space is not finite !

---

**EDIT**

My book has never mentioned "Scheffé's lemma".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\{f_{n_k}\}$ be a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$. Since $f_n \xrightarrow{\mu} f_0$, there exists a subsequence $\{f_{n_{k_j}}\}$ of $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $f_{n_{k_j}} \to f_0$ almost everywhere. Since $\int_\Omega f_{n_{k_j}}\, d\mu \to \int_\Omega f_0\, d\mu$, by Scheffé's lemma, $\int_\Omega |f_{n_{k_j}} - f_0|\, d\mu \to 0$. Since $\{f_{n_k}\}$ was arbitrary, $\int_\Omega |f_n - f_0|\, d\mu \to 0$.

Alternative: Since $f_n + |f_0| - |f_n - f_0| \ge 0$ and $\{f_n + |f_0| - |f_n - f_0|\}$ converges in measure to $2|f_0|$, Fatou's lemma gives

$$\int_\Omega 2|f_0|\, d\mu \le \varliminf \int_\Omega (f_n + |f_0| - |f_n - f_0|)\, d\mu = 2\int_\Omega |f_0|\, d\mu - \varlimsup \int_\Omega |f_n - f_0|\, d\mu.$$

Since $\int_\Omega |f_0|\, d\mu$ is finite (since $f_0 \ge 0$ a.e., so that $\int_\Omega |f_0|\, d\mu = \int_\Omega f_0 < \infty$), we deduce $\varlimsup \int_\Omega |f_n - f_0|\, d\mu \le 0$. Hence $\int_\Omega |f_n - f_0|\, d\mu \to 0$.

Comment: nice idea. but could you please explain what did you do in the last line ?
For any sub-sequence of $\{f_{n_k}\}$, there exists a sub-sub-sequence that the problem's claim holds. but I don't see how did you extend the result to whole sequence. It's sufficient to prove $\int_{\Omega}|f_n-f_0|$ converges and then use this fact that "all subsequence converges to same limit as the sequence", am I right ?

Comment: The point is, a sequence $\{x_n\}$ of real numbers converges to a point $x$ if, and only if, every subsequence of $\{x_n\}$ has a subsequence which converges to $x$. In the case of the problem, $x_n = \int_\Omega |f_n - f_0|$.

Comment: Can I try for another solution to this problem without "almost sure convergent subsequence" and Scheffé's lemma ? Because my book has mentioned this problem before arguing about *almost sure* convergence.

Comment: Why didn't you mention this in the body of your question? It seemed like you knew Scheffé's lemma, but didn't see how it could be applied to the problem.  In any case, I made an edit and gave an alternative proof.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for both proofs. I learned a lot of ideas .

Comment: I think we may solve this little problem, where you've written : $f_0+f_n-|f_0-f_n|\geq0$. Because $f_0$ is not necessarily positive and $f_0+f_n\ngeq|f_0-f_n|$. So we must be more cautious to use *Fatou's lemma* .
And more important, we don't know $\int_{\Omega}|f_0|<\infty$

Comment: I was supposed to put $|f_0|$ in place of $f_0$, but note $f_0 \ge 0$ a.e., so $\int_\Omega |f_0|\, d\mu = \int_\Omega f_0\, d\mu < \infty$. To see that $f_0 \ge$ a.e., note $f_n \xrightarrow{\mu} f_0$ implies $|f_n| \xrightarrow{\mu} |f_0|$. Since $f_n$ is nonnegative, $f_n \xrightarrow{\mu} |f_0|$. Since $f_n$ converges in $f_0$ and $|f_0|$ in $\mu$-measure, $f_0 = |f_0|$ a.e., i.e., $f_0 \ge 0$ a.e..

Comment: Sorry, again, why $\liminf f_n+|f_0|-|f_n-f_0|=2|f_0|$ ?

Comment: @FardadPouran that's not what I said. I said $f_n + |f_0| - |f_n - f_0| \ge 0$ and converges in $\mu$-measure to $2|f_0|$. So by Fatou's lemma for convergence in measure, $\int_{\Omega} 2|f_0|\, d\mu \le \varliminf \int_{\Omega} (f_n + |f_0| - |f_n - f_0|)\, d\mu$.

Comment: I meant Fatou's lemma which says $\int \liminf g_n\leq\liminf \int g_n$, but what is $\liminf g_n$ here ? thanks

Comment: @FardadPouran why do refer back to that version of Fatou's lemma when the one I used is for convergence in measure? Namely, if you have a sequence $(g_n)$ of nonnegative measurable functions on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ and $g$ is a measurable function such that $g_n$ converges in $\mu$-measure to $g$, then $\int_X g\, d\mu \le \varliminf \int_X g_n\, d\mu$.

Comment: Sorry, I had not heard the other versions of *Fatou's lemma* !

Comment: Hello, sorry to bother but how do you prove the last statement of your first proof: because it works for subsubsequences, it works for $f_n$?

Comment: Hi @D.R., it follows from the fact that a sequence converges if and only if every subsequence of that sequence has a further subsequence which converges to the same limit.